# Weird behavior when removing an element from a cloned element in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an ajax application, which receives a list, making a `<li>` html using clone() and append it to `<ul>`.

```
   $.each(arr, function(i) {
    var item = $('#template').clone(true);
        if(arr[i].isTypeA) {
            item.find('.TypeB').remove(); 
        } else {
            item.find('.TypeA').remove();
        }
    });
```

But appended items in `<ul>` have no element (.TypeA) after looping.

Does this problem comes from clone()? or from closure?

I'm searching the solution, but couldn't find yet.

Comment: Can you put your html as well or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem!

After cloning the template, remove the id attribute of the template.

```
item.attr('id', '');
```